# Jpa: delete dependents instead of updating them

Tags: java, spring, jpa, cascading-deletes

In my application every customer can have several accounts. I have the following data structure (a lot omitted for brevity):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @Column(length = 36, name = "CUSTOMER_ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String id;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "OWNER_ID", referencedColumnName = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    private List<Account> accounts;
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @Column(length = 36, name = "ACCOUNT_ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "OWNER_ID", nullable = false)
    private String ownerId;
}
```

If I use JPA to delete a Customer, such as

```
entityManager.remove(customer);
```

it tries to update the related ACCOUNT.OWNER_ID fields with null. OWNER_ID is not nullable, so it throws a JDBCException and rolls back the transaction.

What I need to achieve is that the related ACCOUNT rows get deleted (if any). How can I do that?

Thank you

Update: I tried it with

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
```

but it does not change the behavior: still tries to update with null.

Comment: did you try `@OneToMany(orphanRemoval="true")`?

Comment: I already tried it, but it didnt fix the problem: still trying to update ACCOUNT.OWNER_ID fields with null.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be using cascading in order to remove the child elements. Try this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "OWNER_ID", referencedColumnName = "CUSTOMER_ID")
private List<Account> accounts;
```

You should also reference the Customer in your account by a ManyToOne relationship and not the String id. I think this should solve your issue:

```
@Column(name = "OWNER_ID", nullable = false)
@ManyToOne
private Customer owner;
```

Comment: I already tried it, but it didnt fix the problem: still trying to update ACCOUNT.OWNER_ID fields with null.